# std::cout not printing to console

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(int &pi, int &pj){

    std::cout << "In function swap: " <<  &pi << " " << &pj << "\n";

        int temp = pi;
        pi = pj;
        pj = temp;
}

int main(){

        int i = 10, j = 20;
        int *pi = &i, *pj = &j;
        swap(pi, pj);

        std::cout << *pi << " " << *pj;
        return 0;
}
```

The above program does not give any compilation error. (Though to swap function in not POINTER TO REFERENCE type) and gives the proper output.
But whatever i am trying to print inside **"swap" function is not printed to console**.
Can anybody explain me why?

Comment: Doesn't compile for me. What compiler/version are you using? (Is that your _exact_ code? No extra `using namespace std` by any chance?)

Comment: Well, yeah, it *will* give a compilation error; you can't initialize a reference from a pointer. g++ rejects this program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you're probably using `std::swap` to swap two pointers instead of calling your own swap routine. I suspect you have a `using namespace std;` somewhere that you are not showing us ? Try changing the name of your swap routine to e.g. `my_swap` and then see if calling `my_swap` works (it should fail with a compilation error).

Comment: He never says using namespace std

Comment: @John: That's why I wrote above: *I suspect you have a `using namespace std;` somewhere that you are not showing us ?*

Comment: Yeah, I dint show "using namespace std" (sorry for that). You are right. It was using std::swap. It dint flash to me :)

Comment: right, sorry. I was confused because I didn't see anything in his code haha

Comment: @namith: lesson of the day: avoid `using namespace ...;` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile your program, you don't show us all of your code.
This code snippet you posted doesn't compile, because you're trying to pass to objects of type int* to your function swapm which expects a reference to an int.

If your code compiles, I suspect you to include a 'using namespace std;' anywhere in your original code.

Answer (score -1):

you're trying to get the address of a pointer that you're passing by reference... I don't think you quite understand what you're doing. the pass by reference feature in C++ allows you to pass a reference, so you don't need a pointer. Your code should look like this.

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(int &i, int &j){

    std::cout << "In function swap: " <<  i << " " << j << "\n";

        int temp = i;
        i = j;
        j = temp;
}

int main(){

        int i = 10, j = 20;
        swap(i, j);

        std::cout << i << " " << j;
        return 0;
}
```